# javascript how to pass two values to php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i got following code getting sorting numbers in php ajax page. now i want send single value from two buttons. here is my JavaScript code

```
 function showUser(str)
 {
  if (str==""){
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
  }

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","productlistajax.php?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

now sorting dorpdown menu

```
 <select id="maxDaysSinceAdded" name="shorting" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
   <option selected='selected' value="1">Most Recent</option>
   <option value="2">Lowest Price</option>
   <option value="3">Highst Price</option>
 </select>
```

here is two buttons i want to send single value along with above sorting id.

```
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="-1"    onclick="showUser(this.value)"><< Previous</button> 
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="1" onclick="showUser(this.value)">Next >> </button>
```

NOTE:

please note that when i press next it should add 1 from the previous total and if i press previous then it decrease 1 from total on broad.

and if possible disable previous button when its reach to -1.

thanks n' best regards,

Comment: Please learn to indent your code, nobody is interested in figuring out how your code is nested when you write it without indentation. If you want to get help, at least make it as easy on us as you can.

Comment: Can you explain what these buttons are supposed to do?  I get that the select chooses a sorting option but the buttons do what? Cycle through the sorting options?

Comment: button have same names only value are different...i want to pass values ( 1 or -1 ) to ajax page.

Comment: There are so many things that can be wrong. What's the page's response?

Comment: is 1 and -1 supposed to be the same 'str' variable? or is your ajax page expecting str AND buttonpassvalue?

Comment: it works fine josh.... ok ... 
if anyone can tell me how to send value of click button to ajax page

<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="-1"    onclick="showUser(this.value)"><< Previous</button> 
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="1" onclick="showUser(this.value)">Next >> </button>

Comment: ajax expecting str and buttonpassvalue

Comment: Are -1 and 1 values that increment/decrease? You'd need a local variable to store the actual value if that is the case in order to be able to disable

Answer (score 0):

Its simple ,

Store the value of sort select [maxDaysSinceAdded] into a local variable and pass it to ajax call.

On the ajax request you need to add one more variable separated by '&'.

```
 var sortVal = document.getElementById("maxDaysSinceAdded").value();

 xmlhttp.open("GET","productlistajax.php?q="+str+"&sort="+sortVal ,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

To disable the previous button see if str < 0 [ i.e negative value]

Assign the previous button an id attribute id="buttonpassprevious"

```
 if(str < 0){
   document.getElementById("buttonpassprevious").disabled = true; // Disable
 }else{
   document.getElementById("buttonpassprevious").disabled = false; // Enable
 }
```

at the php end you can get both the values by using the reference variables.

```
<?php
  $buttonVal = $_GET['str'];
  $sortVal   = $_GET['sort']
?>
```

The questioner seems to be a beginner, hence I have extended my answer to the very basic levels for the completeness. Experts please excuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you're buttons do decrease/increase then something like this:

```
<select id="maxDaysSinceAdded" name="shorting" onchange="showUser()">
   <option selected='selected' value="1">Most Recent</option>
   <option value="2">Lowest Price</option>
   <option value="3">Highst Price</option>
 </select>

<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="-1"    onclick="showUser(this.value)"><< Previous</button>
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="1" onclick="showUser(this.value)">Next >> </button>

<script>

function showUser(modifier) {

  // Modifier is the inc/dec value which is optional - default to zero?    
  var bpv = modifier || 0;

  // Str is always there so just grab it from select
  var str = document.getElementById("maxDaysSinceAdded").value;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "productlistajax.php?q=" + str + "&buttonpassvalue=" + bpv, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

But you can't disable the buttons unless you know the current value of whatever it is you are modifying. But I might be  unclear as your goal.

Answer (score 0):

this.value=parseInt(this.value)+1 will add 1 to your previous value

```
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="-1" onclick="showUser(this.value);this.value=parseInt(this.value)-1;"><< Previous</button> 
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" value="1" onclick="showUser(this.value);this.value=parseInt(this.value)+1;">Next >> </button>
```